# Use styles in String format

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am receiving styles as a String, for example as follows.

```
const s = ".some-class .alert{margin:0 auto}.another-class{max-width:1000px;width:100%;margin:0 auto;padding:10px}
aside.sample-class{position:fixed;width:100%;z-index:1002}.sample1-class{position:absolute}.sample2-class:before{content:" "}
html,body{overflow-x:hidden;width:100%;height:100%}
.new-class p{margin:0}";
```

Is there a way I could use it as is or convert it and pass it to an element in a React component?

I can't just do it as follows. It won't work. Please advise.

```
<span
    // neither would work
    style={s}
    className={s}

    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: html.toString(),
    }}
/>
```

Comment: That should be the content of a `<style>` tag not be set as style at an individual element ... what you could do is remove all classnames (ie `.something`)  and curly braces from that string and then try to set the result as stlye. But be aware you have set some properties (for instance `margin` or `width` multiple times)

Comment: Or you could create a `<style>` element and set its content from your string. Note that it's somewhate weird to get a style string like that, basically CSS syntax.

Comment: @Pointy I am actually getting a html via a GET response. I can use the html part of it within dangerouslySetInnerHTML and it works. But it doesn't recognise anything inside the <style>...</style> of that response. Thus I extracted the style part as a String and trying to use it  in the way above. Unless there is a better way to do this. Response is type text/html like: <style>...</style><style>...</style><div></div>

Comment: "html via a GET response" - a better way would presumably be to not do that.

Comment: @Blindy Not much of choice in this instance due to some constraints. It is a partial html response which essentially forms a component. If I call the endpoint on a browser, it works fine. Issue is in using it within a React project.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options that I can see:

### Parse the CSS and insert a prefix

You could pull in a CSS parser from npm and essentially rebuild the CSS with each query selector prefixed with something so that it will be unique. (For instance use `useId` in react and then put that id on your span). Then after generating this you can use either a library like `helmet` or an effect to throw it in the head

### Use a shadow DOM with web components

If you're up for it you could use web components which have mechanisms for scoped styling baked in. Read more about it [on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Components)

### Parse the CSS and manually add it to your elements

This is the least likely to work and would only work for very simple selectors. The basic idea is to pull in a parser from npm parse your CSS then walk the DOM and insert the CSS with inline styles. I don't think this is a very good approach because you will be unable to support pseudo elements and classes.

### Render your HTML and CSS in an iframe

If possible this is the easiest approach. Basically just create an iframe and stick both the CSS and HTML in. This will scope your styles and be easy to do.